# Unitary transform

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ of the same modulus (i.e., the 2-norm), does there always exist a unitary matrix $U$ st $U\vec{x}=\vec{y}$. How to prove this formally?

Comment: Are they unit vecors/do they have the same length? If so, the matrix U is just eg a rotation, which is unitary... Am I missing something?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: $\{ax+by \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a 2D subspace so there is a rotation of that 2D subspace leaving the orthogonal complement unchanged and moving $x$ to $y$. that transformation clearly is unitary

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space.

First suppose that $x, y \in H$ with $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$. Extend $x$ to an orthonormal basis $x, v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $H$ and extend $y$ to an orthonormal basis $y, w_1, \dots, w_n$ of $H$. Let $U$ be the linear map from $H$ to $H$ such that
$$Ux = y \quad \text{  and  } \quad Uv_j = w_j \text{ for } j = 1, \dots, n.
$$
Then $U$ is a unitary map such that $Ux = y$.

Now suppose $x, y\in H$ with $\|x\| = \|y\| \ne 0$. Apply the result in the paragraph above to
$$
\frac{x}{\|x\|} \quad \text{and} \frac{y}{\|y\|}
$$
to obtain a unitary map $U$ such that $Ux = y$, as desired.

Comment: Now I remember why I switched to physics...